# Does the methods in mocked objects work?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

Does the methods in mocked objects work ?
For example if I have an object with method name `Method1` and I mock the object :

```
var mockobject= Mock<myobject>();
```

Does the next call to method work :

```
mockobject.Method1()
```

?

It is a question to clarify about the mock objects.

Comment: Did you call it to test it yourself?

Comment: yes, I just started to use Moq

Comment: well, i kinda did.. and the result was no. But i just wanted to be sure

Comment: The whole point of mocking is creating objects with all the right methods, even though they don't do anything.

Comment: What do you mean with "work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're mocking a concrete class or abstract class with method implementations.  For virtual methods you have two options.

1. Create a `Setup` to fake the method call

   `mockobject.Setup(x => x.Method1()).Returns(true);`
2. Set `CallBase = true` on the mock to invoke the concrete behavior of the `Method1` method.

   `mockobject.CallBase = true;`

Usage:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual int MyMethod()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

[Test]
public void ShouldGiveMeZero()
{
    var mockMyClass = new Mock<MyClass>();

    // returns default(int)
    Assert.AreEqual(0, mockMyClass.Object.MyMethod());
}

[Test]
public void ShouldGiveMeFive()
{
    var mockMyClass = new Mock<MyClass>();
    mockMyClass.CallBase = true;

    // calls concrete implementation
    Assert.AreEqual(5, mockMyClass.Object.MyMethod());            
}

[Test]
public void ShouldGiveMeSix()
{
    var mockMyClass = new Mock<MyClass>();
    mockMyClass.Setup(x => x.MyMethod()).Returns(6);

    // calls Setup
    Assert.AreEqual(6, mockMyClass.Object.MyMethod());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, note that your example will *never* compile:

```
mockobject.Method1()
```

`Method1` doesn't live on the mock object itself--it lives in the underlying mocked object instance:

```
mockobject.Object.Method1();
```

The behavior of that call depends on what `MockBehavior` you're using (`Strict` or `Loose`). It also depends on if the method you're calling is marked `virtual` or not.

If `Method1` is non-virtual, the implementation for the actual type will be used, since Mock cannot mock non-virtual methods.

For example, if `MyObject` is defined like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Method1()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

`mockObject.Object.Method1()` will return `1` since Mock is unable to provide any other implementation for the method.

Now, if `Method1` is declared `virtual`:

```
public virtual int Method1()
{
    return 1;
}
```

The `MockBehavior` comes into play. The default is `MockBehavior.Loose`, which means that methods not defined using the `.Setup` method will return `default(T)` where `T` is the return type of the method. So the following:

```
var mockObject = new Mock<MyObject>(MockBehavior.Default);

int result = mockObject.Object.Method1();
```

Will always return `0` unless you use `.Setup` to make it return otherwise. You can also specify `CallBase = true` on the `Mock<MyObject>` instance and the base implementation will be invoked for methods that aren't defined using `.Setup`.

If you're using `MockBehavior.Strict`, unimplemented methods will throw an exception:

```
var mockObject = new Mock<MyObject>(MockBehavior.Strict);

int result = mockObject.Object.Method1(); // Always throws an exception
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [quickstart guide](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) there are simple examples to get you going, e.g.

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true);
```

Note the call to `Setup` to make the mock/fake actually do something.

Comment: Ok. So it does nothing. I actually have a method in my code that gets called so now i get it why it returns null. So i should use setup to make it do something.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you have created the default stub for Method1. If you were to create this by hand you would have code similar to:

```
public class MyObject {
    public virtual void Method1() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Your stub would be:

```
public class Stub : MyObject {
    public override void Method1() {
    }
}
```

So now instead of getting a NotImplementedException you have an instance of MyObject that will allow you to call Method1 regardless of its original implementation.

Note my usage of **virtual**. Without the usage of virtual there is nothing for Moq to override.

This is actually one of my favorite usages of mocking. Many people go overboard with interfaces for everything "for mocking". The most baseline scenarios only require methods to be virtual. In general I mark nearly every public method I create as virtual. If a public method cannot be virtual, it is likely a violation of the Open Closed Principle.